# How to align a radio button list inside a table with the rest of the table

Tags: asp.net, html-table, webforms, alignment

I'm trying to make the radio button list be align with the rest of the table, even when you reduce the size of the browser window.

```
<div>
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" style="width:100%" align="center">
        <asp:TableRow runat="server" align="center">
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">1</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">2</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">3</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">Result</asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow runat="server" align="center">
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center"></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow runat="server" align="center">
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center" RepeatColumns="3">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center"></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</div>
```

The 2nd table row I used 3 radio buttons instead of a radio button list and is aligned with the 1st row even when the size of the browser window is altered, but the 3rd row is where I used the radio button list and it just does not align at all with the rest of the table.

Here is a print screen for better understanding:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AvhL.png

Comment: Your question is not clear. Align with what? Top, bottom, right, top of screen?

Comment: With the rest of the table, more precisely I want the 3rd row to be like the 2nd one , I can add some screenshots if it's necessary.

Comment: That would probably help...

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: As @IrishChieftain says you do not have the same amount of columns per row. You need to make it the same or use colspan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four columns in the first two rows and only two columns in the third row. So, either add two more columns (TableCells) to the third row or add a ColumnSpan property set to 3 to the cell that has the RadioButtonList to compensate. The rest is just alignment and the use of some CSS.

If you're adding blank cells, add a HTML space for the text property to get them to render correctly. I'm guessing you're using CSS for the table cells/borders.

So, if you just add a ColumnSpan to what you have:

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server" align="center">
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center" ColumnSpan="3"
        RepeatColumns="3">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center"></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

Alternatively, you can add two more blank cells to what you have:

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server" align="center">
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="left" CssClass="radioButtonCell"
        RepeatColumns="3">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" align="center">&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

**CSS:**

Note, this works in the snippet I created. You may have to tweak this. In my example the radio button was too far left.

```
.radioButtonCell
{
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm using the border propriety, could you exemplify what you told, (the ColumnSpan CSS and the HTML space)

Comment: It worked:
https://i.imgur.com/YrBovDO.png but now how can i align the radio button list like the separate radio buttons?

Comment: That's really a separate CSS-specific question. I'm updating my answer (the second example) to align the radio buttons to the left and apply a CSS rule with some padding to the radio button table cell.

Comment: The radio buttons ARE already aligned like the separate ones; they are all center-aligned. Anyway, this question is answered. If you still have some CSS issues, post a new question on SO.